# Typescript - understand interface's indexer

Tags: typescript

The indexer is a bit confusing.

Example:

```
interface Notes {
    [noteId: number]: string[];
}
```

1. Even though I type `noteId` as `number`, I can still pass a string:

```js
var notes: Notes;
notes['1'] = ['Some note'];
```

So I assume coercion happens. But when?

2. Why use square brackets if round brackets works the same:

```js
    interface Notes {
        (noteId: number): string[];
    }
```

Yes, I can use this also as a function, but I would consider this more as an advantage that disadvantage..

p.s. sorry for the mess in the post, seems StackOverflow can't manage to fix this old and annoying bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the difference between

```
interface Notes {
    [key: number]: string;
}
```

and

```
interface Notes2 {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

is that

```
const t: Notes = {};
const t2: Notes2 = {};
t.d = ['value']; // error!
t2.d = ['value']; // OK
```

And the round brackets do not work the same, they define functions, not objects:

```
interface Notes3 {
    (key: string): string[];
}

const t3: Notes3 = {}; // Error! {} not assignable to Notes3
t3.d = ['value']; // Error again! Notes3 has no 'd' property.

const t4: Notes3 = (key: string) => [key]; // OK!
const b = t4('hello'); // b is of type string[] and its value = ['hello']
```

The reason why `t[...]`, `t2[...]` and so on work is, I think (not completely sure), due to the fact that TypeScript does not typecheck indexes in brackets due to performance reasons, or maybe for broad compatibility with JavaScript.

I think that, in past versions, it did typecheck those indexes correctly.

Comment: No, `Notes` has number indexes, while `Notes2` has string indexes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, question about round brackets was my mistake (type wasn't assigned to the object...). Now all makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Regarding first example - you need to turn on `noImplicitAny` compiler option, then you'll get an error as expected.

As for the second one - it is **not** the same, it is "callable signature", for example:

```
interface GetNotes {
    (noteId: number): string[];
}

const getNotes: GetNotes = (noteId: number) => [];
```